# Почему reduce работает именно так?

Tags: javascript

```js
var names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Tiff', 'Bruce', 'Alice'];

var countedNames = names.reduce(function (allNames, name) { 
  if (name in allNames) {
    allNames[name]++;
  }
  else {
    allNames[name] = 1;
  }

  return allNames;
  }, {});
  
console.log(countedNames);
```

1. При первом вызове функции reduce аргумент allNames равен `{Alice: 1}`. Как так получается, что элемент массива становится объектом, где свойство Alice равно 1? Почему не просто `"Alice"`?
2. Почему name равно `"Alice"`, а не `"Bob"`? Ведь по идее allNames, аккумулятор, равняется первому элементу массива names, а name - должен указывать на следующий?

Comment: Вместо `{}` на вход передайте `[]`.

Comment: Тогда результат будет: []

Comment: А вы чего хотите? -.-

Comment: Хотел узнать узнать ответы на вопросы 1, 2. С [] не работает, я так предполагаю, из-за того, что строка if..in с массивом не работает?

Comment: Не работает? У меня на выходе выдаёт `[ Alice: 2, Bob: 1, Tiff: 1, Bruce: 1 ]`, если я `[]` передам.

Answer (score 2):

В параметре для reduce, который задает начальное значение стоит **{}**, т.е. объект. Поэтому все аккумулируется в объект.
Когда объект пустой (на первой итерации) срабатывает

```
allNames[name] = 1;
```

здесь в allNames создается поле с именем по содержимому name и это поле инициализируется значением 1. Получается, что после обработки первого элемента массива  allNames становится

```
{
  Alice: 1,
}
```

Далее добавляется Bob и AllNames становится

```
{
  Alice": 1,
  Bob: 1,
}
```

и так до последнего элемента исходного массива. На последнем элементе срабатывает ветка else в

```
if (name in allNames) {
```

и выполняется

```
allNames[name]++;
```

в результате чего поле Alice принимает значение равное 2

Comment: Спасибо, все стало ясно. Только не понимаю почему, если начальное значение задать не {}, а {'Initial'}, то не работает?

Comment: Потому что так писать нельзя. Initial не инициализирован. Замените например на `{'Initial':0}`

Comment: Да, действительно. Спасибо!